# Having problems with an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am still getting an out of bounds error and I don't know why. I added a print statement to see what the firstList and secondList actually is and it is all messed up I will post the output below so maybe someone can see what is going wrong.

output:

```
Names before sorting: [Justin, Butch, Mandy, Sarah, Jack, Natalie, Brent, Ashley]
[Justin, null, null, null]
[Justin, Butch, null, null]
[Justin, Butch, Mandy, null]
[Justin, Butch, Mandy, Sarah]
[Natalie, null, null, null]
[Natalie, Natalie, null, null]
[Natalie, Natalie, Natalie, null]
[Natalie, Natalie, Natalie, Natalie]
[Justin, null]
[Justin, Butch]
[Sarah, null]
[Sarah, Sarah]
[Justin]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at MergeSorter.sort(MergeSorter.java:22)
    at MergeSorter.sort(MergeSorter.java:25)
    at MergeSorter.sort(MergeSorter.java:25)
    at MergeSorter.main(MergeSorter.java:68)
```

As you can see, the array is all messed up and I don't know why, please help!

```
import java.util.*;

public class MergeSorter
{
   public static void sort(String[] names)
   {
      if (names.length <= 1)
      {
         return;
      }
      String[] firstList = new String[names.length / 2];
      String[] secondList = new String[names.length - firstList.length];

      for (int i = 0; i < firstList.length; i++)
      {
         firstList[i] = names[i];
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstList));

      } 
      for (int i = 0; i < secondList.length; i++)
      {  
         secondList[i] = names[firstList.length + 1];
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondList));
      }
      sort(firstList);
      sort(secondList);
      merge(firstList, secondList, names);
   }   

   private static void merge(String[] firstList, String[] secondList, String[] names)
   {
      int first = 0;
      int second = 0;
      int names1 = 0;

      while (first < firstList.length && second < secondList.length)
      {
         if (firstList[first].compareTo(secondList[second]) < 0)
         {
            names[names1] = firstList[first];
            first++;
         }
         else
         {
          names[names1] = secondList[second];
          second++;
         }
         names1++;
      }
      while(first < firstList.length)
      {
         names[names1] = firstList[first];
         first++;
         names1++;
      }
      while(second < secondList.length)
      {
         names[names1] = secondList[second];
         second++;
         names1++;
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      String[] names = {"Justin", "Butch", "Mandy", "Sarah", "Jack", "Natalie", "Brent", "Ashley"};
      System.out.println("Names before sorting: " + Arrays.toString(names));
      sort(names);
      System.out.println("Names after sorting: " + Arrays.toString(names));
   }   
}
```

Comment: Instead of voting it down, you could tell me what to change about the post. I am here for help!

Comment: I didn't vote you down but its probably because this looks like homework and you posted a lot of code and basically are asking us to debug for you. That being said, the single easiest way to figure out where your array is too small would be to use a debugger and step through the code until the exception happens

Comment: That's what I thought this website was for! It is homework but I have done the work. It's not like I asked for the code so I could copy and paste it. I just can't figure out the error that I keep getting. Where can I find a debugger? I am new to java. Thanks!

Comment: Dustin I posted a possible reason. If you require a longer explanation as to why it's wrong feel free to ask on my answer below. Please confirm whether my output gives you your desired output or not. If not, tell me what your desired output is. Thanks

Comment: some people react that way man. Use Eclipse (free) or intellij. They have a bit of a learning curve but its awesome once you get the hang of it. Avoids littering your code with print statements. Heres a tutorial:  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can use this code  as well to compare the string  as it is simple to compare string :

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is at line 26:

```
secondList[i] = names[firstList.length + 1];
```

That will obviously go outside of the array's bounds, change it to:

```
secondList[i] = names[firstList.length + i];
```

---

And see if you get your desired results:

```
Names before sorting: [Justin, Butch, Mandy, Sarah, Jack, Natalie, Brent, Ashley]
[Justin, null, null, null]
[Justin, Butch, null, null]
[Justin, Butch, Mandy, null]
[Justin, Butch, Mandy, Sarah]
[Jack, null, null, null]
[Jack, Natalie, null, null]
[Jack, Natalie, Brent, null]
[Jack, Natalie, Brent, Ashley]
[Justin, null]
[Justin, Butch]
[Mandy, null]
[Mandy, Sarah]
[Justin]
[Butch]
[Mandy]
[Sarah]
[Jack, null]
[Jack, Natalie]
[Brent, null]
[Brent, Ashley]
[Jack]
[Natalie]
[Brent]
[Ashley]
Names after sorting: [Ashley, Brent, Butch, Jack, Justin, Mandy, Natalie, Sarah]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `secondList[i] = names[firstList.length+i];`?

Comment: It's supposed to be merge sorting. I really don't need the print statements in there until the end. I just put them there to see how the program was breaking the array down. The finished product just needs to put all the names in alphabetical order. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the correction @KonstantinNaryshkin! That is correct, has to be `firstList.length + i`

Comment: Holy Crap! That was all! Thank you both so much for your help!

Comment: Excuse me @Dustin the first code I posted was incorrect, I have edited the post. Thanks again to KonstantinNaryshkin for pointed out the error.

Comment: That's ok! The + i worked! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No worries @Dustin. I presume you can presume why `+ 1` had to be replaced with `+ i`, if not feel free to ask and I can explain. It's self-explanatory really

Comment: Is it because of the the counter being set to i and it's inside loop!

Comment: `firstList.length + 1` will always return the same element as `firstList.length` is always the same, you want it to scale according to your loop, in this case using out `int i = 0`, value of i changes according after each loop so that we loop throughout the array properly